# How to change the size of <li> elements on a Sortable Grid with JQuery ( see images )

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to apply the same functionality from here:

[JQuery sortable as grid](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/display-grid.html)

[image]

He is mine side: How can I change to size (width, height ) in order for the elements to fit when there are line breaks?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to define exact width and height to the li to resolve this kind of issue.